# Problem running eclipse under fedora core 13 x86_64 - runs and exits without even a splash screen

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, fedora

When I try to run eclipse under Fedora core 13 x86_64, eclipse seems to run and then exit without an error.

My install consisted of downloading this file from the Eclipse Amazon mirror:
eclipse-jee-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz

untarring it in my home dir, cd'ing into the reulsting eclipse dir and running the eclipse executable.

The executable seems to run and then exit without displaying so much as a splash screen.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

See below for version details and a run of eclipse with the -debug flag.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
[a1155344@minimi eclipse]$ cat //etc/issue
Fedora release 13 (Goddard)
Kernel \r on an \m (\l)

[a1155344@minimi eclipse]$ uname -a
Linux minimi 2.6.33.5-124.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 11 09:38:12 UTC 2010 x86_64 
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[a1155344@minimi eclipse]$ cat eclipse.ini 
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

[a1155344@minimi eclipse]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
[a1155344@minimi eclipse]$ ./eclipse -debug
Start VM: /usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/a1155344/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /home/a1155344/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/a1155344/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.0.v20100503/eclipse_1307.so
-startup /home/a1155344/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
-exitdata c08023
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-debug
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/a1155344/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar 
Install location:
    file:/home/a1155344/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/home/a1155344/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/home/a1155344/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/home/a1155344/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/home/a1155344/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.6.0.v20100517.jar
Splash location:
    /home/a1155344/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.6.0.v201006080911/splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/home/a1155344/eclipse/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 29
Starting application: 2773
[a1155344@minimi eclips
```

e]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running the correct architecture with the correct JVM.

**64bit Eclipse** needs a **64bit JVM** to run a **32bit Eclipse** needs a **32bit JVM** to run.

Comment: Thanks - now don't I look a d*ck!

Answer (score 0):

Also be certain to use the Sun JVM.  Subtle errors occasionally occur with other JVM's.